# WooCommerce display add to cart without default selection

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I need to display the "add to cart button" without choosing default selection values with variations. 
A customer can select the variable from the dropdown variations and reset the values back and the "single_variation_wrap" should always be visible.
I tried to remove `"display:none"` under `variables.php` but it didn't do the trick.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29574376/7177540)

"WooCommerce: always showing add-to-cart button even before variation is selected"

Comment: The link has an answer to the topic question.

Answer (score -1):

**This should work:**

You can deregister the current *add to cart variation* Javascript, copy and paste this script into your theme directory and enqeue this new one. Here you can remove the slidedown feature and it will always show.

**Caveat**

When woocoomerce push a new release, you will have to check the changlog to see if anything has changed inside add-to-cart-variation.min.js

Comment: I was looking into doing a similar thing so thanks for the answer. Just wondering though, you mention a new `add to cart variation` script but it's not linked to or included. Any chance you would be able to add a link?